# Eclipse plugin run method if selected command in IDE

Tags: eclipse, plugins, command, action, handler

I'm developing an eclipse plugin and i would like to register a handler that is invoked when a command was selected in `Eclipse`.

In my case i need to register a handler that will run after I select `[right-click on a project] -> [Properties]` in `Eclipse` ide

Comment: This is very unclear. Do you want to run something for any command, or a specific command, or just display a property page or what?

Comment: Welcome to SO. 
Please look at [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)